# Redirecting execvp path

Tags: c, system, system-calls, sys

I'm trying to write a simple code which execute a program from subfolders from a input file and print thr result into a output file.

My problem is that when i execute the program it keeps failing on me. since the execvp command is trying to look for an exe named "a.out" on the wrong location. in (desktop rather than searching the correct path address).

here's the code. please help me out :)

```
pid_t   runner;
char enter[] = "/home/demo/Desktop/OS/Ex1/Ex12/code/input.txt"; // input file
char path[] = "/home/demo/Desktop/OS/Ex1/Ex12/Ex1/ronen/"; correct path
char *r [] = {"./a.out", NULL}; 
int savedFD = dup(0);
int sever2Fd=dup(1);
int fdin = open(enter,O_RDONLY);
int fdout = open ("output.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0466);
dup2(fdin,  0);
dup2(fdout, 1);
if ((runner = fork()) < 0) {perror("could not make fork");}
else if (runner == 0) {
    if (execvp(r[0],r) < 0 ) {printf("Failed!\n");}
} else if (runner != 0) {
    waitpid(runner,0,0);
    dup2(savedFD, 0);
    dup2(sever2Fd, 1);
    printf("done\n");
}
close(fdin);close(fdout);
```

Comment: First check the output of getcwd() function to see if you are pointing to correct directory?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple.

"chdir(wanted path)"
int dirchange = chdir(argv[1]);